# Bode plot in Pspice

Tags: mosfet, simulation, buck, pspice, closed-loop

I want to get the bode plot of the controller part of my Buck converter. For this I looked online and saw a technique that mentioned to add an AC injection source from the voltage output to the top resistor of the voltage divider (i.e, R4). But I must have missed something as using the magnitude marker across this V5 voltage source does not work (simulation is not running). How can I get this?

I also need to change the M1 model to averaged switch model, but I need some help on how to do this after I open **Edit -> Pspice Model** or I think it is better to make a new model with the average switch model.
[image]

Comment: You certainly need to resort to an average model in PSpice but you could also check SIMPLIS which will give you the ac response you want from a switching circuit, especially with resonant features as in yours. For a buck operated in voltage-mode control, check one my free 60+ templates working on the demo version and described [here](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf). If you still want PSpice, then you can implement my auto-toggling CCM-DCM PWM switch model described in the many articles I wrote on the subject.

Comment: @VerbalKint Thanks for replying, but I haven't used SIMPLIS, I'm using Pspice right now. I can't figure out if I have to write the "new model" description (i.e .subckt statements till .ends) in a text file or somewhere else, could you clarify this please?

Comment: The PWM switch model has been described in my [APEC 2013](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf) seminar and the DCM/CCM subcircuit for OrCAD has first been presented in my [book](https://www.amazon.com/Switch-Mode-Power-Supplies-Second-Edition/dp/0071823468/ref=dp_ob_image_bk) on SMPS. I recommend that you give SIMPLIS a try, the templates I posted are ready-made and you just need to press F9 to see the cycle-by-cycle waveforms and the ac response in one shot.

Comment: I agree with Chris (@VerbalKint).  SIMPLIS is well worth learning if you are going to be doing power electronics work.  Also Chris has a huge amount of material he's put together that is more than worth checking out, including his book.

Comment: @VerbalKint Apparently there's a [new kid on the block](https://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=AnalogSimMPLABMindi). I just downloaded it and it looks very promising. I can't help wonder what will be the price tag after people get used enough with it.

Comment: @a concerned citizen, thank you, I was not aware of that SIMPLIS version for Microchip but it seems to be around for a few years apparently. I believe it has the same limit for the components and topologies than the current Elements demo? Unless you successfully simulated larger files with it?

Comment: @VerbalKint Alas... 10 states is the maximum.  Foolish hope, that's all. :-)